# Should I approve or reject? Prompt is not clear

Tags: discussion, review-queues, documentation

[I got this review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/126575), but I'm confused by the whole thing. The message says:

> Proposing to remove topic, as it's literally entirely copied and pasted from its GitHub page.

OK, maybe it's a delete? Then below is the text:

> **deletes topic**

The tense and the capitalisation seems a bit off. Perhaps it is a delete? However, the body text has a salmon-pink background and no strike-through of the text. The buttons say <kbd>Approve Change</kbd> and <kbd>Reject Change</kbd>, but it's supposed to be a deletion. Has someone added the text but another reviewer has asked for deletion, so should I reject too, or has someone come along later and voted to delete, so I should approve the deletion change?

I'm very confused!

Comment: Disclaimer: I submitted that deletion. That aside, you're not the only one who got confused with a deletion today. Earlier I had flagged an example in that topic before I investigated the topic further, and somebody went ahead and submitted it for deletion. While it got [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/126570), one of the reviewers rejected it but commented that they agreed the example looked like an advertisement. So I'm going to go ahead and say that deleting stuff in Documentation needs some tweaking.

Comment: I see that other one has the comment/header "**removed 1 example**" - is this user text? Auto-generated? The flag and the "Handles improvement requests" text in the pink also suggests someone added the body text as a response to the improvement request, then the reviewer felt it wasn't up to scratch, so "Reject" is the correct answer.

Comment: Well, it is not going to hurt usability if that button text would say "Approve deletion".

Comment: I happened upon another case of a reviewer [rejecting a deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/126654), but they provided what looks to be ways to improve the example as a rejection reason.

Comment: I'm going to bring this up with the team. It does seem like the prompts and actions could be more clear. Maybe the automated prompt should read something like "This proposed change **deletes the topic**." And also make the change @HansPassant suggests.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because Documentation no longer exists.

Answer (score 9):

This is just a delete request. No more than that.
A deletion is also a "change", so "Reject/Approve Change" makes sense in that way.

The *"deletes topic"* is literally what this change does.

To be honest, I don't see how that request can be interpreted as anything other than a deletion.