# Can we improve reviewing for Documentation delete requests?

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues

I have come up against this a couple of times, and wondered whether there was anything I could do better in my requests, or something that could make the process clearer for reviewers.

Within the documentation (React documentation, [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/1185/components/5937/component-properties#t=201703211938285208947) there is a section that probably should be deleted.  There are improvement requests basically just asking for deletion.

I submitted a delete change for review, and it was rejected by 2/3 reviewers, with the comments:

[image: Review rejection]

Both of which are reasons to support deletion!

Is this just people reviewing too quickly and not paying attention, or is there an improvement that could be made?

Comment: That is indeed not what I intended to be the end-result. It should have been deleted, that was where I voted for, or at least I assumed I *approve* the rejection by also *rejecting* the example...  :(

Comment: That's what i imagined was most likely, and given this is the second time i have encountered a similar situation i am inclined to believe the review page is not clear enough in this situation.

Comment: @rene Rejecting rejects the change, keeping the example. For example, if someone was to suggest an edit deleting a paragraph from an answer, I would *approve* the edit if the paragraph should be removed, and *reject* it if the paragraph should be kept, as well as providing a reason for keeping it. Does that help make this make more sense?

Comment: This sounds like it is a UX issue wrt. what is displayed during review of edits which delete examples. Can we get a/some screenshot(s) of what it currently looks like when the change being reviewed is exclusively the deletion of an example? Is it different than just a normal review of a change? It's been long enough since I reviewed a change which was exclusively removing an example such that I am unsure what might be confusing. However, it does sound like there's more than one person confused, which makes a good case for something being done to clarify what is presented to the user.

Comment: I've been trying to get to review a deletion request, but the docs review queue is generally pretty small, and deletion requests fairly infrequent.  I will keep trying and screenshot it if I come across one.

Comment: @JF it makes sense now and I obviously needed to make this mistake to re-wire my mental model of how to handle this. The question and your comment help and makes much sense, yes. Thanks for that.

Comment: Possibly related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49991/should-yes-delete-it-be-red-or-green/49994

Comment: Not the first time this has come up in regards to deleting documentation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344055/should-i-approve-or-reject-prompt-is-not-clear