# Prevent reviewers from rejecting deletion only edits as "Adds a topic or example that already exists"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, documentation, review-queues

[This proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/135652) to documentation was rejected by 4 users with the reason "Adds a topic or example that already exists." The edit in question only deletes a bit of duplicate content in response to an improvement request that asked the offending content to be deleted. That rejection reason shouldn't be applicable to edits that don't actually add any content. I propose blocking reviewers from rejecting a deletion only edit with that reason. Perhaps displaying a message on the UI if a reviewer tries to do this would be helpful.

Comment: On the other hand, this is a *great* way of catching people who clearly aren't paying any attention in review.

Comment: @animuson Likewise, it could indicate users who misunderstand what they're rejecting. I know in a recent discussion about these rejections, someone (iirc, someone I'd trust not to just make this up) mentioned they thought they were _approving_ the deletion and _rejecting_ the original content. (Or something like that.)

Comment: Related, along with its "Linked" section: [Can we improve reviewing for Documentation delete requests?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345743/can-we-improve-reviewing-for-documentation-delete-requests)

Comment: I agree with @animuson - This seems like a great audit opportunity.

Comment: @animuson Care to turn that into an answer?